# req.body is empty on express POST call

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying ti write a sample POST call in express.

```
var express     = require("express")
    , app       = express()
    , server    = require('http').createServer(app)
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.listen(80, function() {
   console.log("server started"); 
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post("/test", function(req, res) {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.send("working " + req.body.name); 
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("error in test API" + e.message);
        res.end();
    }
});
```

But I am unable to access body data on the server. It is empty. Below is postman query.

[image]

Comment: What data you are sending with the POST request

Comment: @RohitAgrawal it is a form data name=abcd. It is there in postman screenshot.

Comment: Empty object is there `{}`

Comment: Do you want to access data passed from a form or data posted in JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select raw under body in Postman, not form-data if you want JSON data.

Then enter the data in JSON format. Postman should format it if you have the header set: `Content-Type: application/json`

**Edit:**

If you want to parse form-data you can't use body-parser as stated in the readme:

This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:

- busboy and connect-busboy
- multiparty and connect-multiparty
- formidable
- multer

[Github link](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

Comment: @Shubham Can you show a picture of Postman when you try sending it like that?

Comment: I want to access form-data and I changed content-type to `application/json`

Comment: @Shubham Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To read as req.body you're missing the Content-Type : application/json header I think, add it and make the request into a raw json. Or else youre getting a string and cannot directly access it as req.body

eg :

`{"name" : "abcd"}`

<s>Update :</s>

If you need Form data use the bodyParser to convert text to json

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Update 2 :

It seems the issue is with multipart/form-data you're using. To handle it you would need a specific framework like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) due to security issues. The below should work.

```
var multer  = require('multer');

var upload = multer() ;

app.post('/test', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: @Shubham Try setting extended: true

Comment: @KalanaDamel `multer` will work. I used that in separate project. In this form data there is no multipart data I guess. So why `body-parser` is not working.

Comment: @Shubham multipart/form-data is considered as one type of html encoding, so when file uploads through this became a security issue and because of its complexity of data it was taken out of body parser and it was needed to use a middle-ware to access it.