# Node js, Express - Unable to retrieve form data using post method

Tags: node.js, express

My application has post route that accepts the data from postman client. I have written following code to retrieve value of form and print it:

```
var express = require('express');
req.app.use(express.urlencoded());
req.app.use(express.json());
console.log('req.body.name --> ' + req.body.name);
```

Above code prints *req.body.name --> undefined* rather than name value given in field name

I also tried following code:

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
req.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
console.log('req.body.name --> ' + req.body.name);
```

Above code too prints *req.body.name --> undefined* rather than name value given in field name.

Can anyone please guide me on to resolve the issue in retrieving field name?

[image: Attached is the postman request picture.]

Comment: Add the request you are making in Postman to your question. @Malay

Comment: what do you get if you just print req.body?

Comment: printing only req.body.name prints 'Undefined'.

Comment: He asked about `req.body`. You answered about `req.body.name`. You should answer the result of `req.body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used multer to solve this based on inputs from [req.body is empty on express POST call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358287/req-body-is-empty-on-express-post-call?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Posting to benefit others.

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer() ;
app.post('/test', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.body.name);
});
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `req` is used, but `req` is not declared.

You wrote that you used `POST`, but you didn't write an entry point for `POST`.

Please try the following code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));


app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.body.name);  
  res.send(req.body.name);
});


app.listen(3000);
```

The port number is not necessarily 3000.
Use your Postman configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It works in my environment, but I believe your report.

Comment: i dont believe that it worked for you. even body parser documentation says `his does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:`. my guess is that you have sended an JSON format witch works and not an FormData. however you can prove me wrong with evidence

Comment: I see.
I didn't use Postman to make sure it worked.
So I did not focus on multipart bodies.
It is different from the questioner's test data.
I think your opinion is reasonable.

Comment: @Ifaruki - Many thanks for your feedback. Solution doesn't use body parser. It uses multer instead. I rechecked and it works for me. It also works through HTML client too.

Answer (score 0):

```
In your code, proper imports are not there.

1. For Any node application these imports are mandatory
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

2. Use these imports properly like

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));

3. Then use any Http Method like Get, Post, Put, and Delete
Example -
app.post(‘/sample’, (req, res) => {
  // name must be in your request body while requesting for the above API
   console.log(req.body.name);  
  res.send(req.body.name);
});

4. Add the port lister on which Application should run

app.listen(9000);
```

Comment: There was a downvote in my answer, but I want to believe it's not you.
Your answer is my copy, and your code will give an error at run time.

Comment: Vicky, Many thanks. All were declared in preceding code. Here I only wrote relevant code. Once again, many thanks for your feedback. I have posted the solution as well.